# Splitting List into dataframe R

Tags: r

I'm trying to split this list into a long form dataframe

```
list_a <- list(`Blue Banana` = 8.7, `Green Strawberry` = 2.3, 
               `Blue Squash` = 3.5, `Orange Cherry` = 4.5)
```

such that the first column includes the first word in the name of all items in the list (Orange, Blue, Green) and the second column has the second word in the name (Banana, Cherry, Strawberry, Squash). Then the 3rd column will have the values matched. The dataframe should look like this with these column names

```
Color  Fruit      value
Blue   Banana       8.7
Green  Strawberry   2.3
Blue   Squash       3.5
Orange Cherry       4.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)

list_a %>% 
  bind_rows %>%
  gather %>%
  separate(col = key, sep = " ", c("Color", "Fruit"))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Color  Fruit      value
  <chr>  <chr>      <dbl>
1 Blue   Banana       8.7
2 Green  Strawberry   2.3
3 Blue   Squash       3.5
4 Orange Cherry       4.5
```

Comment: Can I use the same approach if I want to break list elements into multiple dataframes?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `read.table()` in base R.

```
cbind(
    read.table(text=names(list_a), col.names=c("Color", "Fruit")), 
    value=unlist(list_a, use.names=FALSE)
)
#    Color      Fruit value
# 1   Blue     Banana   8.7
# 2  Green Strawberry   2.3
# 3   Blue     Squash   3.5
# 4 Orange     Cherry   4.5
```

Or with `strcapture()`.

```
cbind(
    strcapture("(.+) (.+)", names(list_a), data.frame(Color="", Fruit="")), 
    value=unlist(list_a, use.names=FALSE)
)
```

Or a simple call to `tidyr::separate()` with the help of `stack()`.

```
tidyr::separate(stack(list_a), ind, c("Color", "Fruit"))
#   values  Color      Fruit
# 1    8.7   Blue     Banana
# 2    2.3  Green Strawberry
# 3    3.5   Blue     Squash
# 4    4.5 Orange     Cherry
```