# Split a list into separate data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

So I have a list with me as below, what I want is to split them into three separate dataframes (with names as Banana/Strawberry & apple) as shown in expected output. I have already seen this ([Splitting List into dataframe R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682560/splitting-list-into-dataframe-r)) but its exact opposite of what I want. I dont want to combine then I want to split them into three dataframe with same name as list header.

```
list_a <- list(`Banana` = c(8.7), `Strawberry` = c(2.3), `Apple` = c(3.5))
```

DF1

```
Banana
8.7
```

DF2

```
Strawberry
2.3
```

DF3

```
Apple
3.5
```

Any Solution preferably in Tidyverse would be greatly appreciated. Actual problem has lot more columns in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `imap` to get the names and then use `set_names`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
imap(list_a, ~ set_names(tibble(.x), .y)) %>%
        set_names(str_c("DF", 1:3)) %>% 
        list2env(.GlobalEnv)

DF1
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  Banana
#   <dbl>
#1    8.7
DF2
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  Strawberry
#       <dbl>
#1        2.3
DF3
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#  Apple
#  <dbl>
#1   3.5
```

---

If we need separate columns

```
library(tibble)
enframe(list_a) %>% 
     unnest(c(value)) %>% 
     group_split(rn = row_number(), keep = FALSE) %>%
     set_names(str_c("DF", 1:3)) %>% 
     list2env(.GlobalEnv)
DF1
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  name   value
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 Banana   8.7
DF2
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  name       value
#  <chr>      <dbl>
#1 Strawberry   2.3
DF3
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  name  value
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 Apple   3.5
```

Comment: Akrun, if we have to get a separate column in each dataframe stating names of the dataframe could that be done too. For ex: Banana df headers would look like Type & value with first row being Banana & 8.7

Comment: Hi sir, when I run the first solution, I get this `Error in set_names():
! The size of nm (3) must be compatible with the size of x (1).` I will say though that my list has different number of tibbles and different number of rows and columns in each tibble than in the `OP` question. I did not change anything in the code other than providing my list name.

Comment: @Ed_Gravy THE `1:3` assumes that the length to be 3.  May be you need `seq_along(.)`

Comment: @akrun I've reproduced your code, but the 2 new dfs wouldn't keep the column names. Instead 1, 2, 3, 4... is there any modification to keep the column names (the column names are exactly equal for the 2 split dfs)

Comment: @JavierHernando probably you don't have a named list

Answer (score 9):

First convert them all to a tibble:

```r
list_a <- list(`Banana` = c(8.7), `Strawberry` = c(2.3), `Apple` = c(3.5))
list_a <- purrr::map(list_a, tibble::as_tibble)
```

Then send this to the global environment:

```r
list2env(list_a, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This is amazing, Thanks. I have just one problem I think it arises because header of my lists are actually [[1]], [[2]] & [[3]]. So I when run your code last line it gives me below error any help there ?Error in list2env(., envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x

Comment: Ronak's answer takes care of this issue I mentioned above

Comment: Yes if your data doesn't have a named list, you will need to set the names as done in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

A `tidyverse` way would be

```
library(tidyverse)

new_list <- set_names(map2(list_a,names(list_a),  
                    ~tibble(!!.y := .x)), str_c("df", 1:3))
```

and it can be done in base R as well

```
new_list <- setNames(Map(function(x, y) setNames(data.frame(x), y), 
                    list_a,names(list_a)), paste0("df", 1:3))
```

Now we can write it into global environment.

```
list2env(new_list, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: This is just genius. I am fan of you Ronak. It took care of naming list as well. Clever ! An issue which I faced below. IDK if this a stupid question but really appreciate prompt response :)

Comment: @VaibhavSingh yes, to use `list2env` you need a named list. From `?list2env`, `x - a list, where names(x) must not contain empty ("") elements.`. So you need to name the list before using it.

Answer (score 2):

Less straightforward than previous answers but you can get it using a `for` loop:

```r
for(i in 1:length(list_a))
{
  df <- data.frame(unlist(list_a[[i]]))
  colnames(df) <- names(list_a[i])
  assign(names(list_a[i]),df, .GlobalEnv)
}
```